# Error occur while there is no row at position 0

Tags: sql-server, wpf, vb.net

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Imports System.Data

Public Class Window1

    Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btn.Click
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * from tencmpC1 where qnumber='1';", New SqlConnection("Server=(localdb)\Projects;Database=master;Uid=sa;Pwd=12345;"))


        Try

            cmd.Connection.Open()
            Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            adp.Fill(dt)


            txt1.Text = dt.Rows(0)("qnumber").ToString()

            txt2.Text = dt.Rows(0)("topic").ToString()
            txt3.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Umcq").ToString()
            txt4.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Usq").ToString()
            txt5.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Ulq").ToString()
            txt6.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Emcq").ToString()
            txt7.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Esq").ToString()
            txt8.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Elq").ToString()
            txt9.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Pdate").ToString()



            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            txt10.Text = ex.Message
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Above code is from vb file. I have WPF form. What I'm doing wrong please guide me?

Comment: Your query is not returning any data. Try running it directly in a SQL client, and see if it has any results.

Comment: What is the error you get? - if any of `dt.Rows(0)("Pdate")` is `DbNull`  - you will error out

Comment: tnks hanlet i wrongly put another db